# Python - Can't read file - Subprocess

Tags: python-2.7

My small little script opts to rename some files
with a specific ending. For that I read in the file names
and then want to edit the strings with regular expressions.

My problem now is that curiously, when I open the created file
for reading purposes I can't read the lines in it.
When I rune the lines in pythons interactive shell it works.

```
"""
Small script to rename music files
"""


import subprocess
import re



subprocess.call(["touch","temp.txt"])

with open('temp.txt','w') as myfile:
    myfile = open('temp.txt','w')
    p = subprocess.Popen(["ls"],stdout=myfile,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,shell = False    )



with open('temp.txt','r') as file_1:
    text = file_1.readlines()
```

My guess would be that the problem is connected to the
method Popen of subprocess. But it is a huge blackbox for me
and I just copied it from somewhere else.

Greetings

Comment: I guess it's a race condition, since a subprocess created with `Popen` is run asynchronously. Adding a `p.communicate()` (which waits for the subprocess to terminate) will fix the problem, but in fact, `subprocess.call` is enough in your case.

Comment: Thanks works just as intended. Funny I first wanted to use subprocess call      but it didn't work, because I had no idea you can change the output as option, so I changed to popen used in a script I found on stackoverflow. Thanks anyway I learned something new :)